# Scala: type-based list partitioning

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

I have this code that I would like to improve on:

```
sealed abstract class A
case class B() extends A
case class C() extends A
case class D() extends A

case class Foo[+T <: A](a: T)

/** Puts instances that match Foo(B()) in the first list and everything else,
  * i.e. Foo(C()) and Foo(D()), in the second list. */
def partition(foos: List[Foo[_ <: A]]): (List[Foo[B]], List[Foo[_ <: A]]) = {
  // ...
}
```

I would like to improve on this in the following respects:

1. Can I change `partition`'s return type so that it states that there is no `Foo[B]` in the second list?
2. Can I get rid of `Foo`'s type parameter `T` (i.e. change `Foo` to `case class Foo(a: A)`) and still declare `partition` with the same type guarantees? (Obviously, it would have to return something different than `(List[Foo], List[Foo])`.)

P.S.: Let me know if "shapeless" tag is not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 9):

This question is a little tricky because of the way that Scala mixes up [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) (like your `A`) and subtyping. In most languages with ADTs, `B`, `C`, and `D` wouldn't be types at all—they'd just be "constructors" (in a sense that's similar to but not the same as OOP constructors).

It wouldn't make sense to talk about a `Foo[B]` in these languages (like Haskell or OCaml), but in Scala you can, because Scala implements ADTs as case classes (and class objects) extending a base trait or class. That doesn't mean you *should* go around talking about `Foo[B]`, though, and in general if you want to think in FP terms and use the type system to your advantage, it's a good idea not to.

To answer your specific questions:

1. No, not really in any convenient way. You could use a tagged union (a list with `Either[Foo[C], Foo[D]]` elements) or something like Shapeless's `Coproduct` (a list with `Foo[C] :+: Foo[D] :+: CNil` elements) to represent "a list of things of type `A`, but not `B`", but both approaches are fairly heavy machinery for something that probably isn't the best idea in the first place.
2. I'd recommend not parametrizing `Foo` on the subtype of `A`, but if you want to be able to represent "a `Foo` that contains a `B`" at the type level, you're going to need to keep your current approach.

To address your postscript: if you want to generalize over ADTs, Shapeless is definitely applicable—see my blog post [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2014/06/14/partitioning-by-constructor/) about partitioning by constructor, for example. If you're only doing this for `A`, though, Shapeless probably won't buy you much.

---

As a footnote, if I really needed a partitioning operation that split out elements of type `Foo[B]`, I'd probably write it like this:

```
def partition(foos: List[Foo[A]]): (List[Foo[B]], List[Foo[A]]) =
  foos.foldRight((List.empty[Foo[B]], List.empty[Foo[A]])) {
    case (Foo(B()), (bs, others)) => (Foo(B()) :: bs, others)
    case (other, (bs, others)) => (bs, other :: others)
  }
```

It's not ideal—if we really want a `List[Foo[B]]`, it'd be nice to have a `List[Foo[~B]]` to represent the leftovers—but it's not too bad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I don't like having `Foo` parameterized by the subtype of `A`, because most of the time I would just use `Foo[A]`, which does not convey any additional information compared to non-parameterized `Foo`. My partition function can at least return `(List[(Foo, B)], List[Foo])`, so that I don't have to repeat the pattern matching on `B`.

Comment: If I change my `A` to `type A = B :+: C :+: D :+: CNil`, It would be nice to have `B :-: A` to remove `B` from the coproduct `A`. I guess this is impossible to implement?

Comment: You could get evidence that a type is `B :-: A` via a type class, but I don't think that syntax is going to be possible.

Comment: Do you mean a type class, say `AMinusB`, that would be analogous to trait `T` (or `NotB`) from Ionuț's answer?

Comment: Well, a type class at least has the advantage that type class membership can be established ad-hoc.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm about to show is not a very flexible solution. Its usefulness depends entirely on what you're trying to model, but I thought it would be an interesting approach nevertheless.

You could introduce a second trait, say `T`, in the hierarchy and extend all non-`B` case classes from it.

```
sealed trait A
sealed trait T extends A

case class B() extends A
case class C() extends A with T
case class D() extends A with T

case class Foo[+T <: A](a: A)

def partition(foos: List[Foo[A]]): (List[Foo[B]], List[Foo[T]]) = ???
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does not scale well, though. Let's rename your `T` to `NotB`. Then there should be `NotC` and `NotD`, and `B() extends A with NotC with NotD`, `C() extends A with NotB with NotD`, `D() extends A with NotB with NotC`. The boilerplate grows with the square of the number of types, yet it does not convey any new information that is not already present in my original code.

Comment: @TomasMikula yes, I agree about the scaling issue. That's why I added the note in the begging of the answer. I disagree that it doesn't provide any extra information compared to your original code. The return type of `partition` says that the second tuple element won't contain instances of `B`.

Comment: Right. What I meant was that the new definition of A and its subclasses (extending `Not*` traits) does not convey any new information.

Comment: Anyway, `A` and subclasses are defined in a different place (different library actually) than the `partition` function. I want all the extra information necessary to define `partition` to be in the same place as `partition` itself.

Comment: @TomasMikula you might find this answer (and thread) useful. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/8YpX1VkIkDs/dxwBV5m_drEJ It's similar to what Travis Brown suggested with the typeclass, only it's automated by the use of a macro.