# Covariant Trees in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, tree, scalaz

Looking at `scalaz.Tree[A]`, it is invariant in A. I'm looking for a multi-way tree which I can dump values of a hierarchy in

E.g. if I have an ADT of

```
trait MyThing
case object Thing1 extends MyThing
case object Thing2 extends MyThing
```

And I want a Tree of `MyThing`s, I cant use this without doing a cast to `MyThing` in scalaz;

```
import scalaz.{Scalaz, Tree}
import Scalaz._
val tree = Thing1.asInstanceOf[MyThing].
               node(Thing2.asInstanceOf[MyThing].leaf)
```

Which is a bit of a pain.

- Is there are covariant [+A] version of Tree?
- Why is Tree invariant in the first place?

Comment: As an aside, it's safer to use a type ascription `(Thing1: MyThing)` than it is a cast; if changes are made such that there is no longer a relationship between `Thing1` and `MyThing`, the case will compile but fail at runtime whereas the ascription will not even compile.

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/383 is the pull request to look at regarding the removal of variance annotations in Scalaz 7.1; in particular, see the linked PR #328. And I haven't check it's appropriate/possible, but the same technique as `scalaz.IList#widen` uses may be applicable here.

Comment: I'd suggest tackling the problem from the opposite direction—using constructors for your ADT that are statically typed as `MyThing`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Huw - how could I use `widen` on `Tree`? I'm guessing pimping with widen ala IList style `def widen[B](implicit ev: A <~< B): Tree[B] =
    ev.subst[({type λ[-α] = Tree[α @uncheckedVariance] <~< Tree[B]})#λ](refl)(this)`

Comment: Yeah, that's the sort of thing. Highly recommend Travis's suggestion!

Comment: @TravisBrown How could I do this with a `case object`?

Comment: People often point to [Argonaut's `Json`](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/blob/v6.0.4/src/main/scala/argonaut/Json.scala#L468) as a good example of Scala ADT design that downplays subtyping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I want to second Huw's recommendation that you use a type ascription instead of downcasting with `asInstanceOf`. As Huw says, using a type ascription will fail at compile time instead of runtime if something changes in your type hierarchy that makes the cast invalid. It's also just a good practice to avoid `asInstanceOf` for *any* upcasts. You can use `asInstanceOf` for either upcasting or downcasting, but only using it for downcasting makes it easy to identify unsafe casting in your code.

To answer your two questions—no, there's not a covariant tree type in Scalaz, for reasons discussed in detail in the [pull request](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/328) linked by Huw above. At first this may seem like a huge inconvenience, but the decision to avoid non-invariant structures in Scalaz is related to a similar design decision—avoiding the use of subtyping in ADTs—that makes invariant trees, etc. less painful.

In other languages with good support for ADTs (like Haskell and OCaml, for example), the leaves of an ADT aren't subtypes of the ADT type, and Scala's somewhat unusual subtyping-based implementation can make type inference messy. The following is a common example of this problem:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(None)((_, i) => Some(i))
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int]
 required: None.type
              List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(None)((_, i) => Some(i))
                                                     ^
```

Because the type of the accumulator is inferred from the first argument to `foldLeft`, it ends up as `None.type`, which is pretty much useless. You have to provide a type ascription (or explicit type parameters for `foldLeft`), which can be pretty inconvenient.

Scalaz attempts to address this issue by promoting the use of ADT constructors that don't return the most specific subtype for the ADT leaf. For example, it includes `none[A]` and `some[A](a: A)` constructors for `Option` that return an `Option[A]`.

(For more discussion of these issues, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25223200/334519) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25330359/334519)).

In your case, implementing this approach could be as simple as writing the following:

```
val thing1: MyThing = Thing1
val thing2: MyThing = Thing2
```

Which allows you to write `thing1.node(thing2.leaf)`. If you want to go further down this path, I'd highly recommend looking at [Argonaut's `Json` ADT](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/blob/v6.0.4/src/main/scala/argonaut/Json.scala#L468) as a good example of ADT design that downplays the role of subtyping.